# Google maps dynamic center point PHP

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm trying to find out a way which i can have a dynamic center point, rather than have it static, Is there a way i can do this via the bounds method ?

For now i am getting the dynamic location but when the map loads, it is showing the static location, This `new google.maps.LatLng(37.775196, -122.419204);`
Which i want to point my dynamic location when the map loads.

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<?php

  $res = $con->query("SELECT mrk_lat , mrk_lng FROM `marker_info` ORDER BY mrk_id DESC
                      LIMIT 1 ");

  $mrk_cnt = 0;
  while ($obj = $res->fetch_object()){
    $lat[$mrk_cnt] = $obj->mrk_lat;  // save the lattitude
    $lng[$mrk_cnt] = $obj->mrk_lng;  // save the longitude
    $mrk_cnt++;                      // increment the marker counter
  }
  $res->close();
?>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  var point;
  var mrktx;
  function load() {

   addTo = 0;
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.775196, -122.419204);
   var myOptions = {
      zoom: 2,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
              myOptions);
<?php
  for ($lcnt = 0; $lcnt < $mrk_cnt; $lcnt++){
      echo "var point$lcnt = new google.maps.LatLng($lat[$lcnt], $lng[$lcnt]);\n";
      echo "var marker$lcnt = new google.maps.Marker({position: point$lcnt, map: map});\n";
  }
?>
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload='load()'>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 1440px; height: 669px; margin: 0 0 0 0;"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is your "dynamic location"?

Comment: Dynamic locations are the coordinates that are coming from my database .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your PHP variables containing the location using the `echo` shorthand:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$lat[$mrk_cnt]?>, <?=$lng[$mrk_cnt]?>)
```

Or in your code at the end:

```
echo "var point$lcnt = new google.maps.LatLng(" . $lat[$lcnt] . "," . $lng[$lcnt] . ");\n";
```

Comment: Thanks buddy ,
But its not working now the map is not even loading .

Comment: Well, what HTML does PHP generate?